# Erase canvas bitmap with alpha rubber

Tags: java, android

The intention is that the rubber/eraser interacted by user touch take two or more passes over to completely erase the image.

The current code is erasing the bitmap with only touch and I'm working on this direction with no success, any recommendations is also welcome to help

MainActivity.class

```
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new Rachet(MainActivity.this));
    }
}
```

Rachet.class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class Rachet extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    private float mX, mY;

    private Canvas canvas;

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint bitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    private Path rubberPath = new Path();
    private Paint rubberPaint;

    public Rachet(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Rachet(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Rachet(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        rubberPaint = new Paint();
        rubberPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        rubberPaint.setDither(true);
        rubberPaint.setColor(0x0000000);
        rubberPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        rubberPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.BEVEL);
        rubberPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        rubberPaint.setStrokeWidth(100);

        rubberPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR
        ));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldw, oldh);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.foreground), width, height, true));
        bitmapDrawable.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));

        bitmapDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Float x = event.getX();
        Float y = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            rubberPath.reset();
            rubberPath.moveTo(x, y);

            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            rubberPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);

            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            rubberPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

            canvas.drawPath(rubberPath, rubberPaint);

            rubberPath.reset();
            rubberPath.moveTo(mX, mY);
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

[This is an example of a expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyXzk.jpg)

Comment: Off the cuff, the `PorterDuff.Mode` should be `DST_OUT` instead of `CLEAR`, I believe, and then you'll need to set a color with a fractional alpha value, rather than zero; e.g., `rubberPaint.setColor(0x44000000);`.

Comment: Thanks Mike M, this does the trick but with this they draw a various circle transparent following the touch,  I will continue on this way to make it smooth